# Uploading attachment into deals in HubSpot using API

Tags: php, json, api, hubspot

I am having some issues with uploading attachment into deals in HubSpot.

Here is my code:

```
$note_details = array(
        "engagement" => array(
            "active" => true,
            "type" => "NOTE",
            "timestamp" => 5456563646
        ),
        "associations"  => array(
            "dealIds" => array( '4875586081' ),
                "attachments" => array(
                    "id" => array ("44830500634")
            ),
        ),
        
        
        
        "metadata" => array(
            "body"      => "TESTING-222",
        )
    );
```

This code creates an engagement or Notes but the attachment is not there!

and here is the JSON structure that HubSpot uses:

```
{
    "engagement": {
        "active": true,
        "ownerId": 1,
        "type": "NOTE",
        "timestamp": 1409172644778
    },
    "associations": {
        "contactIds": [2],
        "companyIds": [ ],
        "dealIds": [ ],
        "ownerIds": [ ],
        "ticketIds":[ ]
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 4241968539
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "body": "note body"
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?